# sortBy condition using callback function generated by underscore / lodash

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

i have  a javascript model like this :

```
var scope = {
  entries : [ 
      { label : 'one', value : 'first entry'}, 
      { label : 'two', value : 'second entry'}, 
      { label : 'a', value : 'x'}
  ],
  order : 'label'; // may also contain 'value'
}
```

Now i want to order the entries depending on the value of order and cache it too.

I know the way using closures :

```
_.memoize( 
    function() {
        return _.sortBy( scope.entries, scope.order);
    }, 
    _.partial( _.result, scope, 'order')
)
```

Is it possible to replace the closure calling _.sortBy with something similar like the second parameter (the function generated by _.partial) ?

To be clear  : What I want is a way for declaring the 'sortby order' stuff without wrapping it in a function. So that it looks like :

```
_.memoize( 
        // line below doesnt work, just to clarify what i want :-)
    _.sortBy( scope.entries, _.result( scope, 'order')), 

    _.partial( _.result, scope, 'order')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `_.memoize` takes a function to memoize, so no, you can't replace the first argument with a call to the function you're trying to memoize. Your code seems semi-optimal as it stands. On another note, it seems odd to use `_.result` just to grab a property value, I guess so you can use `_.partial` and avoid writing `function`; sure that'll work, but it's a bit confusing perhaps, so why not just use a function there too? Parameterizing it for `scope`, you'd have

```
_.memoize( 
    function(scope) {return _.sortBy(scope.entries, scope.order);},
    function(scope) {return scope.order;}
);
```

Seems pretty clean to me.

Comment: i wanted to know if there is a more declarative way without writing my own closure around. i know how it works with closures but i wanted to know IF IT IS POSSIBLE without writing closures around. Just like the way it works in consumption with https://github.com/dtinth/it.js (but without it :-)

Comment: @Igersman, as I tried to say, it's *not possible*. It's indeed interesting to consider how to use `_.bind` or `_.partial` or whatever in some situations as an alternative to writing callbacks as little functions everywhere, but that's more appropriate when there's very little logic involved; in this case, you're retrieving two properties to pass to `_.sortBy`. If you really want to use `_.bind` or `_.partial` or whatever, you could do it with some helper functions and `Function.prototype.apply.bind(Function.prototype.call,...` or some such, but what's the point?

Comment: Exactly what you proposed is "the point" : a way to express     function(scope) {return _.sortBy(scope.entries, scope.order);} without  writing a closure (i.e. functrion() { ... }) manually. the closure should be generated by lodash. its just a technical question if its possible with lodash.